# Solr - Not finding title with letter 's' at the end

Tags: search, solr

I'm trying to use Solr to find a document which has the title 'UTS Consultants', but when I search this I get the results:

- Auta Consultants
- SomethingelsewithUT Consultants
- UTS Consultants

It seems like the search is not counting the 'S' as part of the search and so not ranking 'UTS'.

I am indexing both a ngrammed and non-ngrammed versions of the title so that fully matched words are ranked higher than partial matches. I figured it was probably stopwords - but I have now removed all stopwords from my stopwords.txt but the problem still occurs.

What could be the problem?

Comment: Post your relevant field definitions and search query

Comment: Appending `debugQuery` to your query should tell you what each part of the query contributes to the total score and the sort order.